# PHP multidimensional array to CSV

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, export-to-csv

I've been spinning my wheels trying to fetch/loop through the values in this multidimensional array in order to create a csv file. My API call returns the following (see image).

How do I place these values in a csv file where, obviously, the header comes first and then the record lines?

Even help with this foreach I'm using for testing would be of value as it returns nothing, but no error:

```
$data = json_encode(array("data" => $report_data));     
foreach ($data->header as $n => $header) {
        $hdr = $header->values->data[0]; 
}   
echo $hdr;
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: json_encode turns an array or object into a string in JSON format. Calling that and then trying to loop over the result doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Is it even possible to loop through the result as shown above?

Comment: Well, since you haven't shown us the actual data, just a blurry screenshot of some unidentified debug view, it's hard to say. Try using `var_export($report_data)` to see it properly.

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to figure it out on my own but thank you for replying.

Comment: If you think your solution would be helpful to others in future, please share it as an Answer below. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PHP array looks like this

```php
$data = [
    'header' => [
        'values' => [
            'data' => [
                'AGENT',
                'TALK TIME',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'records' => [
        [
            'values' => [
                'data' => [
                    'TIM',
                    '194',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'values' => [
                'data' => [
                    'KIM',
                    '135',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
];
```

Then this should do the trick

```php
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $data['header']['values']['data']);
foreach ($data['records'] as $record) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields['values']['data']);
}
```

Comment: Your missing the `values` and `data` keys.

Comment: I adjusted the example above to line up with `values` and `data`

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to figure it out using a different method but thank you for replying.